# A strictly positive solution of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

1.What is the the utility of the existence of a  solution strictly positive of differential equation ?
2. For example $y'(t)=y(t)^3$.

Comment: That is too broad a question.

Comment: You can give some samples.

Comment: Not sure examples of what are you asking. More examples of equations that have a strictly possitive solution for some time?

Comment: What is the differences in properties between solutions strictly positive and any other solutions? The positivity of solution  What means?

Comment: Perhaps the question is :Physically what means a solution strictly positive for a system dynamic?